# Variations of Boundary Actions and Bulk Physics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, boundary-terms

In physics, we are often taught that the action principle generates only bulk equations of motion on-shell and that boundary terms can be neglected provided the fields in question fall off sufficiently fast. In contrast, Randall-Sundrum models ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9905221.pdf),[2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9906064.pdf)), among others, consider an action $$\mathcal{S}[\phi,g_{ab}]=\mathcal{S}_\text{bulk}[\phi,g_{ab}]+\mathcal{S}_\text{boundary}[\psi,h_{ab}],$$ (here $(\psi,h_{ab})$ are the boundary values of the fields $(\phi,g_{ab})$) and derive equations of motion which include terms from variations of the boundary action. Often times these terms enter with $\delta$-functions so away from the boundary the physics is unchanged, but at the boundary the solutions appear highly singular.

My questions are as follows;

> What are the necessary and sufficient conditions which allows a theory
>   to include boundary variations in their equations of motion?

---

> What distinguishes certain boundary/surface terms from others? In particular, I am thinking of the Gibbons-Hawking-York term which is often added to gravitational theories to cancel certain boundary terms which appear from variations.